# Read External XML - XmlReader, XmlDocument, Serialization

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlreader, xml-deserialization

I have to read an external XML file from a website. I am either going to use XMLReader, XMLDocument or Serialization. I need to read this external xml file and then send the values to C# object. Once I have it loaded I need to perform some calculations on some of the fields. These calculations will be stored in fields that are different from the XML file. The reason being my database schema is different form the XML schema. I will need a mixture of the XML fields and new fields to be inserted into the database. Once I perform these calculations I need to send the results to my database. Should I create two objects – One for XML schema and one for Database? Or should I just create the XML schema and add the extra fields that I need to be inserted into the database? Also what would be the best approach for this XMLReader, XMLDocument or Serialization?

Comment: You should have a separate variable for the loaded XML that does not obey the schema. If available, you should use the XDocument class from LINQ to XML. XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Linq To XML to query your XML document.  You can select them as your entity types (e.g. "send the values to C# object").  At this point, you've effectively 'normalized' your data - you can work with these entities to do whatever computations you need, ship them off for persistence, or whatever you need to do.